# C++ - Windows Shell API - Wrong path while iterating through a folder

Tags: windows, api, shell, directory, path

Consider the following code:

```cpp
bool ListFolderContent(const std::wstring& fileName)
{
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl = nullptr;

    if (FAILED(::SHILCreateFromPath(fileName.c_str(), &pidl, nullptr)))
        return false;

    IShellFolder* pShellfolder = nullptr;
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlRelative = nullptr;

    HRESULT hr = SHBindToParent(pidl, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&pShellfolder, &pidlRelative);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
        return false;
    }

    IEnumIDList* pEnumIDList = nullptr;

    hr = pShellfolder->EnumObjects(nullptr, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, &pEnumIDList);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pShellfolder->Release();
        ::CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
        return false;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        LPITEMIDLIST pChild = nullptr;

        hr = pEnumIDList->Next(1, &pChild, nullptr);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            pShellfolder->Release();
            ::CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
            return false;
        }

        if (hr == S_FALSE)
            break;

        wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH + 1];

        if (::SHGetPathFromIDListW(pChild, buffer))
        {
            ::OutputDebugString(buffer);
            ::OutputDebugString(L"\r\n");
        }
    }

    pShellfolder->Release();
    ::CoTaskMemFree(pidl);

    return true;
}
```

This code works well and logs the content of the folder owning the given file I pass through the `fileName` parameter.

However I have an issues with this code: Whatever I pass as file name, the logged path is always C:\Users\Admin\Desktop, and **NOT** the path to the parent folder I'm iterating, as expected. On the other hand the file names are correct.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since you seem to discuss a C++ program here, I suggest that you also tag it with _c++_.

Comment: If you only care about real files and folders, `FindFirstFile` is faster than the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing just the last component ("filename") here: `SHGetPathFromIDListW(pChild, buffer)`. Since the desktop is the root you are basically asking to get the filesystem path of [Desktop] [Filename] from the namespace.

There are two solutions:

- `pShellfolder->GetDisplayNameOf(pChild, SHGDN_FORPARSING, ...)`+`StrRetToBuf`. This is fast since you already have an instance of the folder interface.
- Call SHGetPathFromIDList with an absolute (full) pidl. On the pidl from SHILCreateFromPath, call ILCloneFull, ILRemoveLastID and `ILCombine(clone, pChild)`.

---

```
HRESULT Example()
{
    WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
    GetWindowsDirectory(buf, MAX_PATH);
    PathAppend(buf, L"Explorer.exe");
    
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl, pidlFullItem;
    HRESULT hr = SHILCreateFromPath(buf, &pidl, nullptr); // %windir%\Explorer.exe
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    LPITEMIDLIST pLeaf;
    IShellFolder*pShellfolder; // %windir%
    hr = SHBindToParent(pidl, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&pShellfolder, nullptr);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IEnumIDList*pEnum;
        // Method 1:
        hr = pShellfolder->EnumObjects(nullptr, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, &pEnum);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            for (; S_OK == (hr = pEnum->Next(1, &pLeaf, nullptr));)
            {
                STRRET sr;
                hr = pShellfolder->GetDisplayNameOf(pLeaf, SHGDN_FORPARSING, &sr);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = StrRetToBuf(&sr, pLeaf, buf, MAX_PATH);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) wprintf(L"M1: Item: %s\n", buf);
                }
            }
            pEnum->Release();
        }

        // Method 2:
        ILRemoveLastID(pidl); // %windir%\Explorer.exe => %windir%
        hr = pShellfolder->EnumObjects(nullptr, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, &pEnum);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            for (; S_OK == (hr = pEnum->Next(1, &pLeaf, nullptr));)
            {
                pidlFullItem = ILCombine(pidl, pLeaf); // %windir% + Filename
                if (pidlFullItem)
                {
                    hr = SHGetPathFromIDListW(pidlFullItem, buf);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) wprintf(L"M2: Item: %s\n", buf);
                    ILFree(pidlFullItem);
                }
            }
            pEnum->Release();
        }
        pShellfolder->Release();
    }
    ILFree(pidl);
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The first solution worked for me, but I couldn't get the second one to work. I tried PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pClone = ::ILCloneFull(pidl); + ::ILRemoveLastID(pClone); then with each children ::ILCombine(pClone, pChild); Is it correct? Can you please detail this solution a little more?

Comment: It sounds correct. I would advice you to create a debug helper function that prints out each item in a pidl as ASCII. This PC and c: will be gibberish but you should be able to recognize folders and files. This way you can verify that the pidl path is what you think it is. The first solution is better anyway, with the 2nd the shell is just going to bindToParent to get a IShellFolder and get the name...

Comment: Microsoft recommends that you use IShellItem so that you don't have to deal with these pidl issues. If you only care about XP.SP1 and later it is much less painful.

Comment: Note: SHGetPathFromIDList probably verifies that the item is a filesystem item, GetDisplayNameOf will work on control panel items etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for these information